# Google Reader Java API fails while trying to retrieve feeds for a subscription

Tags: java, rss, feed, google-reader

I used a Google Reader API by Chris Dadswell: [link](http://www.chrisdadswell.co.uk/android-coding-example-authenticating-clientlogin-google-reader-api)
It all worked fine until I created a method for reading feeds from a particular subscription. Here is my code:

```
    public static Document getFeeds(String _USERNAME, String _PASSWORD)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect(
                    "http://www.google.com/reader/view/feed/"
                            + "http%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com%2Ffeeds%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Ftrailers%2Fuploads%3Fv%3D2")
            .header("Authorization",
                    _AUTHPARAMS + getGoogleAuthKey(_USERNAME, _PASSWORD))
            .userAgent("&lt;your app name&gt;").timeout(5000).get();
    return doc;
}
```

The problem is it returns an html which says: "This is taking longer than usual. Try reloading the page".

Answer (score 0):

`http://www.google.com/reader/view/...` URLs are for the regular Reader interface, not for API responses. You'll want to use the [stream contents](http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/ApiStreamContents) API endpoint, e.g. `http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/http%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com%2Ffeeds%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Ftrailers%2Fuploads%3Fv%3D2`.

Comment: I guess the link that you mentioned converts XML feed from http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/trailers/uploads?v=2 into JSON. My question was about the API mentioned by Chris Dadswell at the given link. It's very simple to understand. But it didn't help in my case. Currently I am using a cutsom built FeedReader in my application. Thanks anyways for the info.